# Scala Implementation

Tags: scala

I have a case class:

```
case class EvaluateAddress(addressFormat: String,
                           screeningAddressType: String,
                           value: Option[String])
```

This was working fine until I have a new use case where "value" parameter can be a class Object instead of String.

My initial implementation to handle this use case:

```
case class EvaluateAddress(addressFormat: String,
                           screeningAddressType: String,
                           addressId: Option[String],
                           addressValue: Option[MailingAddress]) {


  def this(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, addressId: String) = {
    this(addressFormat, screeningAddressType, Option(addressId), None)
  }

  def this(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, address: MailingAddress) = {
    this(addressFormat, screeningAddressType, None, Option(address))
  }
}
```

But because of some problem, I can not have four parameters in any constructor.

Is there a way I can create a class containing three parameters: ** addressFormat, screeningAddressType, value** and handle both the use cases?

Comment: You talk about the value of `value` changing, but then you remove it and add two new, different values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala trait implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137581/scala-trait-implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, to use the other constructor's you just need to use the `new` keyword:

```
case class MailingAddress(i: Int)

case class EvaluateAddress(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, addressId: Option[String], addressValue: Option[MailingAddress]) {

  def this(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, addressId: String) = {
    this(addressFormat, screeningAddressType, Option(addressId), None)
  }

  def this(addressFormat: String, screeningAddressType: String, address: MailingAddress) = {
    this(addressFormat, screeningAddressType, None, Option(address))
  }
}

val e1 = EvaluateAddress("a", "b", None, None)
val e2 = new EvaluateAddress("a", "b", "c")
val e3 = new EvaluateAddress("a", "b", MailingAddress(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an auxilliary ADT to wrap different types of values. Inside `EvaluateAddress` you can check the alternative that was provided with a `match`:

```
case class EvaluateAddress(addressFormat: String,
  screeningAddressType: String,
  value: Option[EvaluateAddress.Value]
) {
  import EvaluateAddress._

  def doEvaluation() = value match {
    case Some(Value.AsId(id)) => 
    case Some(Value.AsAddress(mailingAddress)) => 
    case None => 
  }
}

object EvaluateAddress {
  sealed trait Value
  object Value {
    case class AsId(id: String) extends Value
    case class AsAddress(address: MailingAddress) extends Value
  }
}
```

It's then possible to also define some implicit conversions to automatically convert `String`s and `MailingAddress`es into `Value`s:

```
object EvaluateAddress {
  sealed trait Value
  object Value {
    case class AsId(id: String) extends Value
    case class AsAddress(address: MailingAddress) extends Value

    implicit def idAsValue(id: String): Value = AsId(id)
    implicit def addressAsValue(address: MailingAddress): Value = AsAddress(address)
  }

  def withRawValue[T](addressFormat: String,
    screeningAddressType: String,
    rawValue: Option[T])(implicit asValue: T => Value): EvaluateAddress = 
  {
    EvaluateAddress(addressFormat, screeningAddressType, rawValue.map(asValue))
  }
}
```

Some examples of using those implicit conversions:

```
scala> EvaluateAddress("a", "b", Some("c"))
res1: EvaluateAddress = EvaluateAddress(a,b,Some(AsId(c)))

scala> EvaluateAddress("a", "b", Some(MailingAddress("d")))
res2: EvaluateAddress = EvaluateAddress(a,b,Some(AsAddress(MailingAddress(d))))

scala> val id: Option[String] = Some("id")
id: Option[String] = Some(id)

scala> EvaluateAddress.withRawValue("a", "b", id)
res3: EvaluateAddress = EvaluateAddress(a,b,Some(AsId(id)))
```